# Не работает NOT IN MySQL с LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Нужно сделать выборку так:

```
SELECT id,title,data 
FROM #__table
WHERE state=1 
  AND id NOT IN ('" . $arrIds2NAr . "') 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 3
```

где `$arrIds2NAr` - это 1,23,56,89,11,22,45

Получается, есть лимит выборки. Все вроде выполняется как надо. При AJAX запросе данные подгружаются на страницу и в `NOT IN` приходят новые ID которые НЕ НАДО включать в запрос, НО ОНИ ВСЕ-РАВНО ПОПАДАЮТ. Т.е., например, в `$arrIds2NAr` есть ID=25, но он все-равно попадается в выборке. Как это исправить?

Comment: *например, в $arrIds2NAr есть ID=25, но он все-равно попадается в выборке* Показывайте текст запроса ПОСЛЕ подстановки в него параметров. Наиболее вероятная причина - ненужные в тексте запроса одинарные кавычки, которые превращают вставляемый список в один строковый литерал. PS. А вот LIMIT тут точно не виноват...

Comment: SELECT `id`,`title`,`item_data` FROM #__content WHERE `state`=1 AND id NOT IN ('41,191,1,155,231,141,14,35,103,44,159,145,6,276') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3 c ними пробовал и БЕЗ, результат один.

Comment: зачем кавычки внутри IN? у тебя одно строковое значение или набор чисел?

Comment: Вот... ID проверяется на вхождение не в список из 14 числовых значений, а в список из одного длинного строкового литерала. Удаляйте нафиг кавычки.

Comment: чтд  так сказать. @Akina как в воду глядел :)

Comment: Дело в том, что я пробовал изначально без них тестить, но после долгих поисков причины, почему же все-равно попадают ID, которые я как бы исключаю, поставил одинарные кавычки. Т.е. при ajax, я в определенное место складываю все уже полученные ID и потом пытаюсь их исключить, но те, которые выбирались раньше, все-равно проскакивают...

Comment: Запросы не пишут по некоему мистическому наитию. И не отлаживают методом научного тыка. Любая конструкция должна быть логически обоснована -причём в т.ч. на основании строгого соответствия синтаксису.